# Running x86-64 binaries on AArch64 using qemu-system (ArchLinuxArm)

Tags: arch-linux, virtual-machine, qemu, arch-arm

I'm running ArchLinuxArm in a VM on my MacBook M1 (Apple Silicon).

I need to run a couple of x86-64 binaries, so I installed **qemu-user** and **qemu-user-binfmt** packages.

If I try to run any x86-64 binary, I get the following error:

```
qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to install the x86-64 required libraries on ArchLinuxArm?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by manually downloading the x86-64 version of glibc-2.37 package from official ArchLinux repository and then extracting ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 to /lib64.

I don't know if there is a better way to obtain the x86-64 version of glibc-2.37 directly from ArchLinuxArm tho. It surely would be better to install the package instead of manually extracting just a .so file!